# Handling nil (null) values in nested relations in Rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, null

The project currently I'm working has the following code in the view:

```
<%= product.provider.name %>
```

The above code is get the 'provider' for a product and display his/her name. But my question was sometimes this code fails when'provider' gets nil. (I know it's little unusual but since I'm working with a legacy db this happens)

So to check the nil validation I have written the following code (in my ApplicationHelper)

```
def t(obj, attr)
    obj.nil? ? "" : obj.send(attr.to_sym)
end
```

Now what I do is something like this:

```
<%= t(product.provider, "name") %>
```

Even though this works, I ran in to another problem, I found this code:

```
<%= product.provider.provider_type.title %>
```

The problem here is, in the above code either 'provider' or 'provider_type' can be nil.

What I'm looking at is an exception handling mechanism to handle any number of nested relationship.

Or is this a completely wrong path  to handle nil values in nested relations? I'm running on Rails 2.3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rescue all exceptions:

```
<%= product.provider.provider_type.title rescue nil %>
```

Comment: That would work, but note that it effectively blocks you from ever discovering any bugs. You could type `product.totallybogus.would.never.work rescue nil`, and nobody would ever complain (which might be nice, or not :)).

Comment: @Casper, yeah, you are totally right. But it's one of the options. :)

Comment: Hi @nash, rescue nil is working great, Just wanted to know if there if a common way of using this, instead of added it in every line, thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is a common problem. You might want to check these:

- [Object.try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)
- [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/)

Examples:

```
# With try
product.provider.try(:name)
product.provider.try(:provider_type).try(:title)

# With andand
product.provider.andand.name
```

Comment: Casper's suggestion is what I have typically done, defining _? to daisy-chain calls and have a graceful failure. +1

Answer (score 1):

since we can use **#try** methods or handle the exceptions inline, this method of usage breaks the Law of Demeter: *Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.*

views should get the ready-to-use ojbects/variables, not chains. so you can try to use **delegate** method within models and cover other else with helpers. keet your views as clean as possible, look at them from designer's point of view.

Comment: Good point mikhailov. Sometimes we forget the basics of Good Design with all the blinkelights to play with in the language.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

```
class Object
  def unless_nil(default = nil, &block)
    if nil?
      default
    else
      block[self]
    end
  end
end

product.provider.unless_nil(&:name)
product.provider.unless_nil(&:provider_type).unless_nil(&:title)
product.provider.unless_nil("Not specified", &:name)
```

It is also quite convenient to have `Object#unless_blank`, `Array#unless_empty`, `Hash#unless_empty`.

**Added:**

Meanwhile using full block is even more convenient in some cases:

```
some_variable = 
  product.provider.unless_nil do |provider|
    # some complex logic here using provider
  end
```

I like it more than:

```
provider = product.provider
some_variable = 
  if provider
    # ...
  end
```

or using `product.provider` everywhere. Matter of taste though.

Comment: rails core has the almost same method **#try**

Comment: @mikhailov My project is still on 1.2.6, so I don't have access to `try`

Comment: this method source is almost the same as yours **unless_nil**

Comment: def try(method, *args, &block); send(method, *args, &block); end

Comment: @mikhailov No, it is not the same (I can check rails source too ;) ). Your method will cause an exception unless you define it in Nil class also by the way. Besides, I don't need args or block in case of association, but I do like scoping the way I showed. As I said it is a matter of taste.